# JQuery - Hide parent div if child div haven't similar or like data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

i want to hide country name when user type airport and the country don't have similar airport name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#from').focus();
  $('#from').on("keyup", function() {
    $(".wrap-airport-from").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, "fast");
    if ($(this).val()) {
      var input = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      console.log(input);
      //alert(input);
      $(".airport-from").hide();
      $(".airport-from[data-kode*='" + input + "']").show();
    } else {
      $(".airport-from").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="from">
<div class="wrap-airport-from">
  <div class="list-country">
    <b>Indonesia</b>
    <div class="list-airport">
      <a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="jakarta">Jakarta</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-country">
    <b>Australia</b>
    <div class="list-airport">
      <a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="sidney">Sidney</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

above code only hide airport name and still show country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery function `.parents()` to select and hide the corresponding parent element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#from').focus();
  $('#from').on("keyup", function() {
    $(".wrap-airport-from").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, "fast");
    if ($(this).val()) {
      var input = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      console.log(input);
      //alert(input);
      $(".airport-from").hide();
      $(".airport-from").parents('.list-country').hide();
      $(".airport-from[data-kode*='" + input + "']").parents('.list-country').show();
      $(".airport-from[data-kode*='" + input + "']").show();
    } else {
      $(".airport-from").show();
      $(".airport-from").parents('.list-country').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="from">
<div class="wrap-airport-from">
  <div class="list-country">
    <b>Indonesia</b>
    <div class="list-airport">
      <a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="jakarta">Jakarta</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-country">
    <b>Australia</b>
    <div class="list-airport">
      <a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="sidney">Sidney</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DediAnanto : I have updated the answer to handle backspace and delete. Added `$(".airport-from").parents('.list-country').show();` to `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#from').focus();
 $('#from').on( "keyup", function() {
  $(".wrap-airport-from").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
  if($(this).val()) {
   var input = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
   console.log(input);
   //alert(input);
   $(".list-country").hide();
   $(".airport-from[data-kode*='"+ input +"']").parents('.list-country').show();
  }else{
   $(".list-country").show();
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="from">
<div class="wrap-airport-from">
 <div class="list-country">
  <b>Indonesia</b>
  <div class="list-airport">
   <a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="jakarta">Jakarta</a>
            <a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="bali">Bali</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="list-country">
  <b>Australia</b>
  <div class="list-airport">
   <a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="sidney">Sidney</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this could fix your problem

Comment: this code hide country name, but i also want to filter airport and your code not filter airport name if inside country div has more than one airport
`<b>Indonesia</b>
<div class="list-airport">
 <a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="jakarta">Jakarta</a>
</div>
<div class="list-airport">
 <a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="bali">Bali</a>
</div>` @pugazh answer fix the problem

Comment: Ok just made some changes on above html '<a href="#" class="airport-from" data-kode="bali">Bali</a>' and worked fine... you can check it by clicking on Run code snippet button of my answer

Comment: thank @veshraj-joshi. but what i want is when user type bali, program hide jakarta. when type jakarta, hide bali. like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ymwsn3ny/)